# Android GLES20 - Program not linking

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am using GLES20 to create a shader program. Link status is false and `GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program)` return just an empty String.

The shaders themselves seem to compile corrently, as `GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status, 0)` gives true for both vertex and fragment shader.

As `GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program)` returns just an empty string, it's really difficult to debug and the shaders look correct to me, but I apparently have missed something. Has anybody any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**Now simplified code and shader:**

```
private static String vertexSrc = "#version 100\n" +
        "#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH\n" +
        "precision highp float;\n" +
        "#else\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "#endif\n" +
        "\n" +
        "attribute vec3 position;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "void main() {         \n" +
        "\t\n" +
        "\tgl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "}";
private static String fragmentSrc = "#version 100\n" +
        "#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH\n" +
        "precision highp float;\n" +
        "#else\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "#endif\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "void main() {       \n" +
        "\n" +
        "\tgl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "}";

private void initShader(){

    int vertexShader = loadShader(vertexSrc, GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(fragmentSrc, GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    System.out.println("Created program: " + program);

    System.out.println("Attaching " + vertexShader + " to " + program);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    System.out.println("Attaching " + fragmentShader + " to " + program);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    int[] attached = new int[2];
    int[] count = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetAttachedShaders(program, 2, count, 0, attached, 0);
    System.out.println("attached (" + count[0] + "): " + attached[0] + ", " + attached[1]);

    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");
    //GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "texCoord");

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);

    int[] lstatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, lstatus, 0);
    if (lstatus[0] == GL11.GL_FALSE){
        System.err.println("Could not link program.\nlink status: " + lstatus[0]);
        System.err.println("Program-Info-Log: " + GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
    }else{
        System.out.println("program linked: " + program);
    }

    GLES20.glValidateProgram(program);

    int[] vstatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(program, GLES20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, vstatus, 0);

    if (vstatus[0] == GL11.GL_FALSE){
        System.err.println("Could not validate program.\nvalidate status: " + vstatus[0]);
        System.err.println("Program-Info-Log: " + GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
    }else{
        System.out.println("program validated: " + program);
    }

}

private int loadShader(String shadercontent, int GL20_XXX_SHADER){

    //System.out.println(shadercontent);

    if(GL20_XXX_SHADER == GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        System.out.println("Loading vertex shader...");
    else if(GL20_XXX_SHADER == GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        System.out.println("Loading fragment shader...");

    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GL20_XXX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shadercontent);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
    int[] status = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status, 0);
    if (status[0] == GL11.GL_FALSE){
        System.err.println("Could not load shader: \n" + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
    }else{
        System.out.println("Shader compiled: " + shader);
    }
    return shader;
}
```

Output:

```
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x9f7467c4
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1536x2048]-format:1
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xae57b4c4
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1536x1872]-format:1
I/System.out: Loading vertex shader...
D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : net.mypackage.myapp
I/System.out: Shader compiled: 1
I/System.out: Loading fragment shader...
I/System.out: Shader compiled: 2
I/System.out: Created program: 3
I/System.out: Attaching 1 to 3
I/System.out: Attaching 2 to 3
I/System.out: attached (2): 1, 2
W/System.err: Could not link program.
W/System.err: link status: 0
W/System.err: Program-Info-Log: 
W/System.err: Could not validate program.
W/System.err: validate status: 0
W/System.err: Program-Info-Log:
```

Comment: I tried also with nearly empty shaders and still the same problem. Looks like the source of the problem is not in the shaders.

Comment: Have you tried on other devices? If there is an error in the shader code another device might give you better information about it. I suspect you've ran into a bug in a specific GLES implementation, so simplifying might be a good idea. One random thing to try: In your VS, texCoord0 is implicitly highp, and in your PS it's implicitly mediump, try making them match.

Comment: @Columbo I tried with 2 physical deevices an 1 emulator. The thing is, that the emulator gives true for link and validation status. I will test with explicit precision today and come back.

Comment: @Columbo Thanks, but unfortunately setting explicit precision to texCoord0 did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment, yet to the main question. Therefore I have to write an answer. Could you remove the glValidateProgram please, to see whether it is the reason why the info log is empty? Because the program may be valid after a failed link you could have overwritten the info log with glValidateProgram with an empty string after glLinkProgram.

**UPDATE**

Your fault is that you check your program's status with glGetShaderiv instead of glGetProgramiv. This leads to an GL_INVALID_OPERATION error. In the developer options of your mobile phone you can turn on OpenGL tracing, which will display this error to you. That also explains why your info log is empty. glGetShaderiv wasn't successful and doesn't know what is wrong with your program. glGetProgramiv would give you successful back.

Comment: Thanks, but the info log is still empty. I've read about this being a bug.

Comment: Did you try explicitly stating the version of the shaders? I mean #version 100 or something like this at the top of each? I've experienced problems when not explicitly stating the version in GLES/GLSL.

Comment: I tried now `#version 100`, with no success. Still the shaders compile successfully, but the program will not link.

Comment: Are you sure that both, the fragment shader and vertex shader are compiled as the correct shader type? I mean maybe you have some sort of copy and paste error inside or so. Could you give us the compilation code, too?

Comment: I have now simplified the code and the shaders (with no luck) and put it into the question. I hope that helps to help. :)

Comment: Uhm you use glGetShaderiv on a program. It leads to an GL_INVALID_OPERATION. You need to use glGetProgramiv.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! You saved me.